# How to divide html page vertically and set a full height background?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

note: i'm using bootstrap, if it could help somehow.

```
.html, css, container {
height: 100%;
}
```

My problem is, i cant set it in html or body class (like some solutions suggest), because i dont want it to every pages. I just need this in one page.

I've tried to aplly it to my custom DIV but it wont work if I dont have content inside. Height is set to 100% but stills 0px, unless i put some content inside that div.

Comment: `body, html { height: 100% }` ?

Comment: Sounds like a clearfix is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to the `<html>` tag for the page you wish to have 100% height

```
<html class="full-height-page">
```

Then use this CSS below

```
.full-height-page,
.full-height-page body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%; /* this is necessary */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add this style to this particular page

```
        body, html {
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Then use this. This code divides the page into 2 columns vertically and vertically align the contents. Content on the left is center-aligned. Only bootstrap classes are used. Call bootstrap 4 beta ver to apply the code.

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-sm-6 styled-bg">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
                <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
                    This is left column
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center h-100">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    This is Right column
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```